# CORS still blocked between two DDEV sites

Tags: cors, ddev

I'm trying to make an ajax call to Site A from Site B. I've edited the `nginx-site.conf` file and removed the `#ddev-generated` comment so my changes aren't removed on `ddev restart`.

This was added in the nginx config:

```
location / {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://craft-b.ddev.site';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 3600;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';

        absolute_redirect off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

The error I still receive:

"Access to fetch at 'https://craft-a.ddev.site/actions/login-share/test' from origin 'https://craft-b.ddev.site' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Not sure if there's additional config I need to do that relates to DDEV. There was an old Github issue I was trying to follow from 2018, but I didn't really see anything relevant.

Comment: What does `ddev exec ping craft-b.ddev.site` say? Have you looked at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/faq/?h=faq#can-different-projects-communicate-with-each-other ?

Comment: `ping` gives me `64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.183 ms`. I did add the `docker-compose.communicate.yaml` file which allowed me to make Guzzle/CURL request to the other DDEV site. But no luck with CORS

Comment: Using the communicate.yaml should help. Now what do you get with `ddev exec ping craft-b.ddev.site` ?  Sounds like that part is working. Is your request that's failing coming from JS or from PHP ? From JS, it's coming from the host, from PHP from the web container. The problem is probably different based on those. (You should probably join us in Discord for faster interaction and answers, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k )